# How to capitalize first and third letter?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to capitalize first letter and third letter in my textarea.

I can capitalize only first letter and then every next letters and words are transformed to lowercase.

If there is any solution for this problem, please tell me.

I am using AngularJS.

This is what im trying and did.

```
  link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
        //console.log('init');

         controller.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
          var transformedInput = (!!inputValue) ? inputValue.charAt(0).toUpperCase()  + inputValue.substr(1).toLowerCase() : '';
                      if (transformedInput != inputValue) {
            controller.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
            controller.$render();
        }

        return transformedInput;
    });
```

This works only for first letter, it transforms to uppercase and then transforms another letter and words to lowercase.

I tried to change my code into this but nothing.

```
  var transformedInput = (!!inputValue) ? inputValue.charAt(0).toUpperCase()  + inputValue.substr(1).toLowerCase()  + inputValue.charAt(3).toUpperCase() + inputValue.substr(4).toLowerCase(): '';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this. Same as what you are doing just using for loop to identify the character index to modify.

```js
var inputValue = "test";

var transformedInput = '';

if(inputValue){
    for(var i=0; i<inputValue.length; i++){
   if(i===0 || i=== 2){
     transformedInput += inputValue.charAt(i).toUpperCase();
        } else {
         transformedInput += inputValue.charAt(i).toLowerCase();
    }
  }
}

console.log(transformedInput);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function to capitalize chars at specific positions

```
function capitalizeAtPositions(string, indexes) {
  (indexes || []).forEach(function(index) {
    if (string.length < index) return;

    string = string.slice(0, index) +
      string.charAt(index).toUpperCase() + string.slice(index+1);
  });
  return string;
}
```

Run it as follows:

```
var test = "abcdefg";
var result = capitalizeAtPositions(test, [0, 2]);
//AbCdefg
```

In your case i think it will be something like (can't test it without jsfiddle):

```
var transformedInput = capitalizeAtPositions(inputValue || '', [0, 2]);
```

Comment: can i just replace this code into mine ? i need it to input version not for text. when i will input something it should capitalize first letter and for example third letter. I think this is only for texts not input

Comment: @brithwulf yep, you can. If you need to change text as you type, you will not be able to do it that easily. you will have either to use `div contenteditable` or some more advanced solution, like `CodeMirror`, i think.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing how you need to have the input change as you type, you'll probably need a directive; here's a one to capitalize the given letters of any input with an ng-model:

https://plnkr.co/edit/hWhmjQWdrghvsL20l3DE?p=preview

```
app.directive('myUppercase', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      positions: '=myUppercase'
    },
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

      scope.positions = scope.positions || []

      function makeString(string) {
        if (!string) return;
        angular.forEach(scope.positions, function(pos) {
          string = string.slice(0, pos) + string.slice(pos, pos+1).toUpperCase() + string.slice(pos + 1)
          console.log(string)
        })
        return string;
      }

      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(makeString)
      ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(makeString)
    }
  }
})
```

HTML:

```
<input ng-model="value" my-uppercase="[0, 2]">
```

Answer (score 1):

My simple solution

```
var inputValue = 'your value';

function toUpper (str) {
    var result = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (i === 0 || i === 2) {
            result += str[i].toUpperCase();
        } else {
            result += str[i].toLowerCase();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
var transformedInput = toUpper(inputValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution for "McArturo" this type of text you want

```
$("#LastName").keyup(function () {
var last_name = $("#LastName").val();
var op = last_name.substr(0, 2);
if (op == "mc" || op == "Mc" || op == "MC") {
    $("#LastName").val("Mc" + (last_name.charAt(2).toUpperCase()) + last_name.substr(3).toLowerCase());
} else {
    $("#LastName").val(last_name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + last_name.substr(1).toLowerCase());
}});
```